# JSP markup inside <tiles:put> or a or an alternative

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

I've inherited an old application that is using Struts 1.2 Tiles 1. For various annoying reasons I can't upgrade.

I'm not very familiar with Struts, or specifically Tiles in general and I'm trying to do something that makes sense in my head but I can't seem to make work in practice. Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<tiles-definition>
    <definition name="content-with-sidebar" path="/content_with_sidebar.jsp">
        <put name="top"     value=""  type="string" />
        <put name="sidebar" value="/tiles/sidebar.jsp" />
        <put name="main"    value="" type="string" />
        <put name="bottom"  value="" type="string" />
    </definition
</tiles-definition>
```

content_with_sidebar.jsp

```
...
<tiles:insert attribute="top" flush="false" />
<div id="content">
    <aside>
        <tiles:insert attribute="sidebar" flush="false" />
    </aside>
    <div id="main">
        <tiles:insert attribute="main" flush="false" />
    </diV>
</div>
<tiles:insert attribute="top" flush="false" />
...
```

actual_page.jsp

```
<tiles:insert definition="content-with-sidebar" flush="false">
    <tiles:put name="top" type="string">
        <div>Maybe this page has something on the top that isn't the page header</div>
    </tiles:put>

    <!-- use the default sidebar -->

    <tiles:put name="main">
        <strong>Current Location:</strong>
        <address><h:outputText value="#{locationDesc} #{zipCode}" /></address>
        <!-- Some more dynamic jsp markup -->
    </tiles:put>

    <!-- This one doesn't have anything extra on the bottom -->
</tiles:insert>
```

This almost works but the dynamic bits get rendered above and outside the `<tiles:insert>` and the plain strings go where they should. I understand now, after much searching, that `<tiles:put>` in this, er, context, is expecting a plain ole string.

Is there a pattern to accomplish what I want with dynamic context?

As it stands I'm having to create another jsp file to be referenced by the   `<tiles:put>` tag. i.e.

```
<tiles:put name="main" value="/actual_page_body.jsp" />
```

I'd rather not have to create an additional file when one would do. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With tiles, when the definition is rendered (content-with-sidebar in your code), the jsp corresponding to the 'path' attribute (/content_with_sidebar.jsp) will be invoked. All other jsps have to be manually invoked using a `<tiles:insert>`. What tiles provides you is a way to configurationally invoke them as definition attributes.